# Why is ngOnChanges executed when modifying a local property of a class?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been dealing with this scenario for a while, I appreciate your advice in advance

`ngOnChanges` runs in a context that I understand it shouldn't run. When modifying a property of a class which was initially set through `@Input`. This modification causes `ngOnchanges` hook to be executed in one context and not in another. I describe my scenario below

I have the following parent component that contains a list of customers that is passed to a child component,

Parent controller

```
export class AppComponent {
  customers: ICustomer[];
  currentlySelected: Option = 'All';

  constructor() {
    this.customers = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Task1',
        status: 'Pending',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Task2',
        status: 'Pending',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Task3',
        status: 'Progress',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Task4',
        status: 'Closed',
      },
    ];
  }

  selectBy(option: Option): void {
    this.currentlySelected = option;
  }

  filterBy(): ICustomer[] {
    if (this.currentlySelected === 'All') {
      return this.customers;
    }

    return this.customers.filter(
      (customer) => customer.status === this.currentlySelected
    );
  }
}
```

Parent template

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li (click)="selectBy('All')">All</li>
    <li (click)="selectBy('Pending')">Pending</li>
    <li (click)="selectBy('Progress')">Progress</li>
    <li (click)="selectBy('Closed')">Closed</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<app-list [customers]="filterBy()"></app-list>
```

Before passing customer to the child component they are filtered according to the customer status property, that is the purpose of the `filterBy` function.

The child component in the hook `ngOnChanges` modifies each customer by adding the `showDetail` property and assigns it the value `false`

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() customers: ICustomer[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.customers = changes.customers.currentValue.map(
      (customer: ICustomer) => ({
        ...customer,
        showDetail: false,
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('init');
  }

  toggleDetail(current: ICustomer): void {
    this.customers = this.customers.map((customer: ICustomer) =>
      customer.id === current.id
        ? { ...customer, showDetail: !customer.showDetail }
        : { ...customer }
    );
  }
}
```

Calling the `toggleDetail` method changes the value of the `showDetail` property to show the customer's detail

child template

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customers">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <button (click)="toggleDetail(customer)">Detail</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="customer.showDetail">
        <td colspan="2">
          <pre>
            {{ customer | json }}
          </pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The behavior that occurs is the following, when all clients are listed and click on detail it works as expected, but if I change to another state and the list is updated and I click on detail it does not show the detail. The reason is that the `ngOnchanges` hook is re-executed causing the `showDetail` property to be set to false again, thus defeating my intention.

Why is `ngOnChanges` executed in this context? What alternative is there to solve it?

**Update 1**

I have added sample app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkvvgt?file=src/list/list.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You has in your code

```
<app-list [customers]="filterBy()"></app-list>
```

Angular can not know the result of the function "filterBy" until executed, so it's executed each time check. This is the reason we should avoid use functions in our .html (We can use, of course, but we need take account this has a penalty). Use an auxiliar variable

```
customerFilter:ICustomer[];
```

In constructor you add

```
constructor() {
    this.customers = [...]
    this.customerFilter=this.customers //<--add this line
  }
```

And in selectBy

```
  selectBy(option: Option): void {
    this.currentlySelected = option;
    this.customerFilter=this.filterBy() //<--this line
  }
```

Now pass as argument the customerFilter

```
<app-list [customers]="customerFilter"></app-list>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxjgyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs `ngOnChanges` when any of the inputs change. When you use an object as an input parameter Angular compares references. As Eliseo said Angular calls your `filterBy` function on each change detection, and it's not a problem when the `currentlySelected` is `All`, beacuse you return the same array reference and it won't trigger change detection in your list component. However when it's not, that causes an issue. You `filter` your array on each change detection and that results in a new array every time. Now Angular detects that the `@Input()` changed and runs `ngOnChanges`.

You can do as Eliseo said, that's a solution too. My suggestion is to create a pipe, it's makes the `component.ts` less bloated.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterCustomers',
})
export class FilterCustomersPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(customers: ICustomer[] | null | undefined, filter: Option | undefined | undefined): ICustomer[] | undefined {
    if (!customers) {
      return undefined;
    }
    if (!filter || filter === 'All') {
      return customers;
    }
    return customers.filter((customer) => customer.status === filter);
  }
}
```

I prefere writing out `null | undefined` too, so it's safer with `strictTemplates`.

You can use this pipe like this:

```html
<app-list [customers]="customers | filterCustomers : currentlySelected"></app-list>
```

Here you can read more about [Angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Another suggestion:
Your `nav` doesn't have `button` elements, you bind your `(click)` events on `li` elements. That's a really bad practice as it not focusable by keyboard. More about [HTML Accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML).